# Why is a postback not being triggered?

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple web form, but when I submit the button postback is always false. This should all happen on the same page.

```
<form runat="server" class="frm" method="post" action="">
    <span><input type="radio" name="options" value="Milk" /><label>Option 1</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="options" value="Butter" /><label>Option 2</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="options" value="Cheese" /><label>Option 3</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="options" value="Milk" /><label>Option 4</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="options" value="Butter" /><label>Option 5</label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="options" value="Cheese" /><label>Option 6</label></span>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="vote" />
 </form>
```

**Button Code **

```
<asp:Button ID="loginBtn" runat="server" Text="vote" OnClick="Login" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Noon Silk said, you need to use server side controls, but you also need to use the asp.net mechanism on the form tag; see example code below. Notice the form tag has a 'runat="server"' attribute rather than a method and action:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not using the .net controls; you are just doing it manually.

You'd need to use an ASP.NET button, like so:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" ... />
```

And same for your inputs, if you want to be able to access them through `txtFoo.Text`. Of course, if you don't, you can still access everything through `Request[...]`.

Comment: Is there anyway to trigger the postback without having to use asp.net controls?

Comment: I suppose if you look at the JavaScript generated by the asp.net controls, and then copy that manually, it would work, but I wouldn't personally recommend it.

Comment: I changed it to the server control but it still doesn't generate a true for postback when clicked. See post for updated code